# mySQL datetime and timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to update mysql rows where DATETIME < TIMESTAMP

DATETIME is like: "2014-06-21 17:56:00"

TIMESTAMP is like 1454546656 (which is now)

I want to update all the rows where DATETIME is in the past

What's the lightest method to deal with a huge number for rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PHP, try using the PHP Date Function:

```
$ts = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp); //Convert Unix Timestamp to MySQL Date/Time Format
UPDATE table WHERE DATETIME < '$ts';
```

This is the lightest method I can think of, because it is not recalculating the timestamp for each record, and furthermore, if the DateTime Field is indexed, it will go incredibly fast.

Answer (score 2):

In mysql there 2 function which are

`from_unixtime()` to convert the unix time to human readable date

`unix_timestamp()` to convert a human readable date to timestamp

So you can use one of then for the comparison

Here how it looks

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1454546656);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1454546656) |
+---------------------------+
| 2016-02-04 06:14:16       |
+---------------------------+


mysql> select unix_timestamp('2014-06-21 17:56:00');
+---------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('2014-06-21 17:56:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                            1403353560 |
+---------------------------------------+

mysql>  select unix_timestamp('2014-06-21 17:56:00') < 1454546656;
+----------------------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('2014-06-21 17:56:00') < 1454546656 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  1 |
+----------------------------------------------------+

mysql>  select from_unixtime(1454546656) > '2014-06-21 17:56:00';
+---------------------------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1454546656) > '2014-06-21 17:56:00' |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 1 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

So its upto you which one you want to use for the comparison.

Comment: Agreed but I don't think this all is necessary as `datetime < NOW()` should be enough for his use case.

Comment: yes if you use now it should work, the above is just an illustration if you have the values `1454546656` as input.

Comment: Only Issue I can see, is this is recalculated with every record. Not sure how that would impact performance as not the case with my solution.